# Send order refund to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I get all the information about the order and sent it to google analytics (http://www.google-analytics.com/collect) through PHP curl.
My data:

```
Array
(
    [t] => transaction
    [ti] => 5555
    [tr] => 200.00
    [ts] => 10.00
    [tt] => 5.00
    [cu] => EUR
    [v] => 1
    [dh] => test.com
    [dl] => http://test.com/
    [dr] => http://test.com/index.php?
    [tid] => UA-XXXX-1
    [cid] => 452396293
)
```

Everything works fine, I can see the orders in Google Analytics system.

How to cancel an order now? I need send refund status to GA, but how?

By google doc need add "pa=detail".

But what I still need to send there? How looks like "Hit type" (t)?
Maybe somebody can show refund example.

Comment: send the same data back again only with negative values will remove it. well not really remove it there is no way to really remove it it just kinda negatives it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pa=detail` is merely an example in the documentation. pa is "product action" and might be one of: *detail, click, add, remove, checkout, checkout_option, purchase, refund* (and obviously you want the refund).

And while I have not tested this serverside a product action with the javascript tracking code would need a hit to be sent (the docs suggest an event with a non-interaction event) so you'd have to send a pageview or event.

Answer (score 0):

Ecommerce transactions that have been fully or partially refunded can be programmatically uploaded to Google Analytics by using the Management API. 
There is a good [Importing Refund Data using the Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/data-import-refunds) article on the developer docs.